# How can I always yank text to clipboard?

Tags: neovim

I'm currently switching to NeoVim using Mac, and unfortunately the yank key doesn't always work as I expect.

I currently use :%w !pbcopy to copy entire documents.

Is there any problem if I remap the yank key to something like !pbcopy? Do you have any tips for that?

Comment: I don't know about NeoVim, but Vim has the `clipboard=autoselect` option that automatically copies to the clipboard whenever you highlight anything with visual mode.

Comment: wow, it has been a long time since I've started learning Vim, I currently just type gg + 0 + v + shift G + y to copy everything, it's obviously not the best way, but I grew used to it

Comment: You might get better answers asking this question in [Vi StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), which accepts questions for Vim and Neovim too.

Answer (score 5):

This tells vim/nvim to use the system clipboard for all yank, delete, change and put operations:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

I forget if this works on Mac. You might need to use `unnamed` instead of `unnamedplus`, or do something like this:

```
if has("unnamedplus")
    set clipboard=unnamedplus
else
    set clipboard=unnamed
endif
```

Comment: This does not seems to work on ubuntu-22.04

Comment: @FabriceJammes I'm not sure why it wouldn't. I'm on Pop OS 22.04 and it works.

Comment: @FabriceJammes had to install xclip: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15212/neovim-clipboard-selection#comment73456_15213

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to the other answer, non-macOS users will also need to ensure that the right clipboard tools are installed. You can view requirements via `:h provider-clipboard`. For example, for Linux + Wayland setup, you can install `wl-clipboard`. After logging out and back in, I was able to get a shared clipboard running with `:set clipboard=unnamedplus` in neovim.